# If start of line is http:// and end of line is com, append * at end of line

Tags: bash, sed, bash-scripting

I have a file.

http://example.com
http://example1.com

How can i achieve with sed that if a line is starting with http:// and ending with com, append * on end of line

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed '/^http:\/\/.*com$/s/$/*/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

```
url='http://example.com'
```

You can achieve it without using `sed` using [Regular expressions](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) in bash.

```
[[ $url =~ ^http: ]] && [[ $url =~ com$ ]] && url="$url*"
```

That means: If the url starts with `http:` and ends with `com`, `$url` is now the same as before with an `*` at then end.

However, if you want to use `grep`, you can use:

```
[[ -n `echo 'http://example.com' | grep ^http | grep com$` ]] && url="$url*"
```

`-n` is testing if the result of the grep operations is not void, and only in that case append the `*` to the url.